# when am going to access my magento application in another system within the same network but it's not working

Tags: php, magento

When I'm going to access my magento application in another system within the same network, it's not working. So I have changed the option in `admin/store/configuration/web` base url as `127.0.0.1`

> <---error----->
>
> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Invalid URI passed as string (http://127.0.0.1/Magento/admin/http:/index/127.0.0.1/Magento/admin/admin/index/index/key/340b03b40a3bd841fdc1fbfe18d05c3677fb06490f8d39f7842668ea8bd12291/?SID=2tdm2rapk83scle9t276cmlj70/key/2ada0f8216f4ff138e6a556f4f361bfd62bce4d0bcb896f02eab9deb551851a1/&SID=2tdm2rapk83scle9t276cmlj70)
>
> Error log record number: 447387072
>
> <---error end---->

Please provide me some solution.

Comment: You have space after `127.0.0.1`? check it

Comment: yes but where should i remove that space...my admin panel is not opening.it simply showing that error

Comment: You have to remove it directly from database

Comment: from which table i should remove..i have already changed the base url as localhost in core_config_data table

Comment: In `core_config_data` table change value for `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` path